# How to improve gain of class A amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio

I constructed the following two circuits:

1. Fixed bias amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fslDEy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2. Voltage divider bias circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fobGby.png)</sup>

Upon experimenting, I found that the fixed bias circuit has more gain and the output is less distorted. In the second circuit, which is actually a stable one as books say, the output gain is very less (I could hear feeble output when I kept speaker close to my ears) and also the output is very distorted. What should I do to get a clear output?

Comment: In the 2nd circuit, you connected your bias supply with incorrect polarity. But the main problem with your circuits is that you are using pullup resistors much lower than the load impedance. You need to replace R1 and/or Rc with a current source if you want to have any chance at a good circuit. Then you will have to do something to stabilize the output voltage DC point.

Comment: @mkeith, isn't the load resistance 4\$\Omega\$?

Comment: what do u mean by pull up resistor being less than load impedance

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say much higher than the load impedance. For example, Rc is 100, which is much higher than 4 (the load impedance). As long as this is the case, the output amplitude will be severely limited. @SoumyaSambeetMohapatra, you really need to study some basics of electronics before you try to design an amplifier for a loudspeaker. Maybe read a book or two, or study some other circuits, such as Bride of Zen. Bride of Zen is not a great amp, but it is simple and gives you a better idea of what is required.

Comment: I guess I meant "Zen amplifier" not "bride of zen."

Comment: @mkeith, why will the Rc value limit gain?

Comment: Well how much current can you get from 12V through a 2K2 resistor? What output voltage will that develop across your 4 ohm load?

Comment: @Chu The transistor outputs a **current** which goes into the impedance connected to its collector. So that is Rc for DC current and Rc in parallel with 4 ohm of SPKR1 for AC. Now think about the situation when SPKR1 is not there, the AC current can only go into Rc which is 100 ohms. Now connect SPKR1 again, the AC current can now also go into SPKR1, it is only 4 ohm so the total Rc is about 4 ohm (4 ohm with 100 ohm in parallel is about 4 ohm). The AC current into 4 ohm gives 25 times less voltage gain than that same current into 100 ohms.

Comment: @SoumyaSambeetMohapatra You expect too much from a single transistor amplifier. It simply cannot deliver so much gain and power at the same time. Open an old audio amplifier, count how many transistors it has. That's about how many you need. Follow mkeith's advise and study it. There is no other way to learn.

Comment: @FakeMoustache In both circuits (which are not well designed, but that isn't the question) most of the output signal current goes through the speaker, and the collector resistor serves to fix the quiescent operating point. The OP's observation is that circuit 2 has far less gain than circuit 1, and it's obvious that the power supply polarity in  circuit 2 is wrong. So fix this first and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

In order to look at the output levels, ignore the coupling capacitor and consider what happens when the transistor goes from full on to full off. In the first circuit, full on will ground the load. Full off will allow a load voltage of (4/104) x 12, since the load will form a voltage divider with the load. This is about 0.46 volts AC. Now try the second. With the transistor on, output and the emitter resistor are in parallel, with an effective resistance of (4 x 100)/(4 + 100) or 3.846. This gives an output voltage of .02094 volts. With the transistor off, output voltage is .02178. So the most the second circuit can possibly put out is .84 mV AC.

So your underlying problem is simply that your 2.2k collector resistor allows so little current into the load that the load power never gets very large.